# Javascript Regex to get 2 characters and all characters between

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very basic understanding of Regex and am finding this difficult to achieve.

There is a html select with numerous options like this

```
<select>
  <option value="%001% 25cm Single" label="%001% 25cm Single">%001% 25cm Single</option>
  <option value="%002% 25cm Single" label="%002% 25cm Single">%002% 25cm Single</option>
  <option value="%003% 25cm Single" label="%003% 25cm Single">%003% 25cm Single</option>
</select>
```

%001%, %002% etc is going to be used to order the options, the opening % and closing % as well as the content between also needs to be hidden from the frontend. However, before any of this can be done the %xxx% neededs to be grabbed with regex.

So what is needed, it seems, is to match the first occurrence for each option of a string that starts with a %, followed by any 3 digits, followed by another %. The numbers between the % are what need to be returned for ordering

There also needs to be a regex rule that matches and returns both the % and the 3 numbers between then so that they can be hidden from the front end using jquery.

So far I have

```
/^%.{3}%/
```

All help appreciated

Comment: Just curious as to why you are "ordering" the options. The options will be ordered in the order in which you output them in the HTML source, so why the need to provide an order tag in the source?

Comment: the . will match anything. What you want in this case is \d: /%\d{3}%/        As i'm a numpty when it comes to remembering to use quantifiers, i'd actually type /%\d\d\d%/ in this case.

Answer (score 0):

for getting the %123% parts use: `%[\d]{3}%`

Comment: No need for the character class; the regex `%\d{3}%` is equivalent.

Comment: yeah, I was indeed writng %[0-9]{3}% ;). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, to find all characters up until another stop character, you can use either:

```js
/[^%]+/ // One or more characters which are not a % character
/.+?%/  // One or more non-newline characters, as few as possible, up to a %
```

So, to find a `%` followed by anything up until the next `%`, you can use either:

```js
/%[^%]+%/
/%.+?%/
```

However, if you know that there must always be exactly three digit characters, then you should use that (more restrictive) regex:

```js
/%\d{3}%/
```

If you want to preserve any part of the match for separate reference, make it a "capture" by enclosing it in parentheses. Each capture will come out as a separate part of the array returned by `String.prototype.match`:

```js
var marker = /%(\d{3})%/;
var string = "%001% 25cm Single";
var results = string.match(marker);
var number  = results && results[1]; // "001"
```